# Whether the series converges uniformly on [0,1]

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, uniform-convergence

Consider the following series $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{xe^{-nx}}{\ln n}.$$

It is easy to see that it converges uniformly on $[a,1]$ for any $a>0$. I want to show that it does converge uniformly on $[0,1]$.

I have tried some values like $x=1/n$ and then letting $n\to\infty$ but this did not work:

$$\sum_{n=k}^{2k}\frac{1/k\cdot e^{-n/k}}{\ln n}\geq(k+1)\frac{e^{-2}}{k\ln 2k}\sim\frac{1}{e^2\ln 2k}$$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it is uniformly convergent: For $x \in (0,1]$ and $1\le k<l$:
$$
0 \le \sum_{n=k+1}^l \frac{xe^{-nx}}{\ln n}\le \frac{1}{\ln(k+1)}x \sum_{n=k+1}^l(e^{-x})^n =  \frac{1}{\ln(k+1)} x\frac{e^{-(k+1)x}-e^{-(l+1)x}}{1-e^{-x}}
$$
$$
= \frac{1}{\ln(k+1)} \frac{x}{1-e^{-x}}(e^{-(k+1)x}-e^{-(l+1)x}) \le \frac{1}{\ln(k+1)} \frac{x}{1-e^{-x}}.
$$
Now  $x\mapsto \frac{x}{1-e^{-x}}$ is increasing on $(0,1]$. Thus for $x \in [0,1]$:
$$
0\le \sum_{n=k+1}^l \frac{xe^{-nx}}{\ln n}\le \frac{1}{(1-e^{-1})\ln(k+1)},
$$
(for $x=0$ this inequality is trivially true).

Thus $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{xe^{-nx}}{\ln n}$ is a uniform Cauchy series on $[0,1]$, hence uniformly convergent.

Comment: Slightly shorter: $\sum_{n=k+1}^l \frac{xe^{-nx}}{\ln n}\le \frac{x}{\ln(k+1)} \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-nx} = \frac{1}{\ln(k+1)} \frac{x}{1-e^{-x}}$

Comment: Or even directly upper-bound $\sum_{n>k}$ instead of invoking the Cauchy criterion: the $k$-th rest of the series converges uniformly to $0$ as $k\to\infty$.